# An expression for a specific "run" of a university course

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

Suppose we have courses such as

- Math 101
- Advanced physics

and so on.

Each course is taught twice a year

- Math 101 during Spring 2022
- Math 101 during Fall 2022
- Advanced physics during Spring 2022
- Advanced physics during Fall 2022
- Math 101 during Spring 2023
- ...

What is one such "instance" called?

The direct translation from my mother tongue is "**course round**" but I find basically zero mentions of such phrase when googling.

I've found [some references](https://documentation.brightspace.com/EN/le/course_templates_offerings/admin/course_offering_properties.htm) to "**course offering**" but when googling course offering, 95% of the results are about "what courses a school offers", not individual runs of a course.

Surely there must be a well established expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is **no** standard, established term with this meaning that one can expect to be readily understood across different institutions. A particular institution may have a term for this purpose as a part of its own terminology, but even that is not usual. The terms proposed elsewhere on this page may be usable for this purpose, if their intended meaning is clearly indicated by the context, but not otherwise. When academics need to speak of such matters, they usually resort to the formulations such as 'This course is offered twice every year' or 'The next time I teach this course, I plan to use a different textbook'.

Answer (score 0):

As in Hot Lick's comment, *session* is the right word, and *spring session* or *fall session* makes the time scope unambiguous.

Comment: This may be an OK word to use for this purpose, **if** the context makes it clear that this is what is intended, but it cannot be assumed that it will be so understood apart from a disambiguating context. One should also bear in mind that at some institutions *session* may be an already established technical term with a different meaning.

Comment: There's no difficulty using session in two different senses at the same institution. Spring session, and morning session.